# Extract minimum multiple of 5 from a list of doubles in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, min

I would like to extract the minimum multiple of 5 from a list of doubles. Here is an example data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)

z <- tribble(
  ~x,
  c(65, 80, 101),
  c(70, 66, 92),
  c(65, 42, 84),
  c(30, 70, 101),
  c(82, 66, 55)
)
```

Ideally the output would be a new column with the minimum odd number from the each list:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  x             y
  <list>    <dbl>
1 <dbl [3]>    65
2 <dbl [3]>    70
3 <dbl [3]>    65
4 <dbl [3]>    30
5 <dbl [3]>    55
```

Comment: minimum odd number of minimum multiple of 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use map from purrr, to apply a function to each nested tibble. I think this should work:

```
library(purrr)
z %>% mutate(y=map_dbl(x,~min(.x[.x %% 5==0])))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  x             y
  <list>    <dbl>
1 <dbl [3]>    65
2 <dbl [3]>    70
3 <dbl [3]>    65
4 <dbl [3]>    30
5 <dbl [3]>    55
```

or using map alone, you unnest y:

```
z %>% mutate(y=map(x,~min(.x[.x %% 5==0]))) %>% unnest(y)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to add the minimum multiple of 5:

```
z$y <- vapply(z$x, function(e) min(e[e %% 5 == 0]), numeric(1))


# A tibble: 5 x 2
  x             y
  <list>    <dbl>
1 <dbl [3]>    65
2 <dbl [3]>    70
3 <dbl [3]>    65
4 <dbl [3]>    30
5 <dbl [3]>    55
```